# Why is .html() method returning extra code than what is in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/m7q3H/52/

I'm accessing the html returned within the div "toupdate". I expect it would return just         `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6343621.js"></script>`
Instead it is returning :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6343621.js"></script><a name="pd_a_6343621" style="display: inline; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"></a><div class="PDS_Poll" id="PDI_container6343621"><div style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px;" name="PDI_form6343621" id="PDI_form6343621"><div class="pds-box"><div class="pds-box-outer"><div class="pds-box-inner"><div class="pds-box-top"><div class="pds-question"><div class="pds-question-outer"><div class="pds-question-inner"><div class="pds-question-top"> New Poll</div></div></div></div><div class="pds-answer"><span id="pds-answer6343621"><span class="pds-answer-group"><span class="pds-answer-input"><input class="pds-radiobutton" type="radio" id="PDI_answer28688772" value="28688772" name="PDI_answer6343621"></span><label for="PDI_answer28688772" class="pds-input-label"><span class="pds-answer-span">Answer A</span></label><span class="pds-clear"></span><br></span><span class="pds-answer-group"><span class="pds-answer-input"><input class="pds-radiobutton" type="radio" id="PDI_answer28688773" value="28688773" name="PDI_answer6343621"></span><label for="PDI_answer28688773" class="pds-input-label"><span class="pds-answer-span">Answer B</span></label><span class="pds-clear"></span><br></span><span class="pds-answer-group"><span class="pds-answer-input"><input class="pds-radiobutton" type="radio" id="PDI_answer28688774" value="28688774" name="PDI_answer6343621"></span><label for="PDI_answer28688774" class="pds-input-label"><span class="pds-answer-span">Answer C</span></label><span class="pds-clear"></span><br></span></span></div><div class="pds-vote"><div class="pds-votebutton-outer"><a id="pd-vote-button6343621" class="pds-vote-button"><span>Vote</span></a><span class="pds-links"><a href="javascript:PD_vote6343621(1);" class="pds-view-results">View Results</a><br><a href="http://polldaddy.com/signup-free/?ad=poll-front" target="_blank" class="pds-pd-link">Polldaddy.com</a><span class="pds-clear"></span></span><span class="pds-clear"></span></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><img src="http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel?a.1=p-18-mFEk4J448M&amp;a.2=p-ab3gTb8xb3dLg&amp;labels.1=type.polldaddy.poll" style="display: none;" border="0" height="1" width="1" alt="Quantcast"></div><div id="PD_superContainer"></div>
```

Where is this code coming from? Can I access all of this javascript code via a seperate jquery method instead of .html() ?

Fiddle code :

```
<body>
    <div id="toupdate">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6343621.js"></script>
    </div>

    </body>​

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('HTML is '+$('#toupdate').html());
});​
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is output by the JS at `http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6343621.js`

`.html()` maps onto `.innerHTML` which serialises the live DOM to HTML, it doesn't get the original source.

If you want the original source you need to make a new HTTP request to the URI of the document and then process it as text.

Comment: the js at http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6343621.js is different to the js returned by .html()

Comment: `.html()` doesn't return the JS from that file, it returns the HTML it outputs.

Comment: So I need to make a request to http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6343621.js and process the result as text ?, what is meant by process as text ?

Comment: If you want to get `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6343621.js"></script>` then you need to make a request to the URI of your HTML document (definitely not the .js file) and then not have it treated as HTML (so that the JS in it doesn't run).

Comment: If you want to get the JS source, then you need to make a request to `http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6343621.js`

Comment: making a request to http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6343621.js using "$.getScript" breaks the "Same Origin Policy" so this cannot be done ?

Comment: Not directly, you'd have to proxy it through either the same origin or something that implements CORS or JSONP.

Answer (score 2):

The script has some `document.write()` calls, which are evaluated to add content to the page.

When the browser sees that `<script>` tag, it loads the script and executes the code immediately. The content written to the page by the script code, therefore, ends up inside that `<div>` element because the closing tag has not yet been seen (by the browser).

Comment: can the js generated by the document.write() calls be access via jQuery ?

Comment: @user470184 yes - the jQuery code runs *after* the document has been modified by the script. The jQuery code just uses the native browser's `.innerHTML` accessor to get the contents, and that always returns the current, as-modified contents of the element (as opposed to the element as it looked in the original HTML).  That is, if *anything* changes the DOM, then `.innerHTML` will reflect those changes.

Comment: Also, the script is *not* generating JavaScript - it's generating HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the script is generating some stuff inside `touupdate`

[image]